# How to find and substitute contents for multiple files at the current directory using shell script or linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

I have the current folder name as `details1` and the current folder has list of files like `file1`, `file2`, `file3` and so on...

Example:(Here I had showed only the `file1` and other files will also  contain the same contents as `file1`.)

```
file1:cat file1

 href="/de_hecklist/secry/GD/GD10/"

 href="/de_hecklist/secry/GT/GT1/"
```

My query:

How to use find and substitute for multiple files(i.e `file1`, `file2` and `file3` and so on) under the current directory with one time substitution without opening the each file .

I had tried the following:(This is applied by opening each files)

```
:%s/de_hecklist/data/g

:%s/secry/send/g
```

Excepted output should be as follows for multiple files under the current directory:

```
href="/data/send/GD/GD10/"

href="/data/send/GT/GT1/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this line give the correct output

```
 sed -e 's/de_hecklist/data/g' -e 's/secry/send/g' file1
```

then you can change the content `in-place` with `-i`

```
 sed -i -e 's/de_hecklist/data/g' -e 's/secry/send/g' file1
```

To do that with all files which matches say `file?` you can

```
find . -name 'file?' -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/de_hecklist/data/g' -e 's/secry/send/g' {} \;
```

You can also give `sed` all the files as parameters. Fist make a command which gives all the full-path-filenames:

```
find . -name 'file?' -type f
```

Then add this to `sed`:

```
sed -i -e 's/de_hecklist/data/g' -e 's/secry/send/g' $(find . -name 'file?' -type f)
```

Comment: The construction in the last command (`sed` with `$(find...)` as parameters) **must** be prohibited, especially when you have a working solution with `find -exec`.  What if some filenames contain space characters? (not with your pattern `file1?` of course, I'm speaking of the general case) Or, worse, contain the string " -n " (with spaces around) which would instruct sed to not print any line at all, thus emptying the files that it edits?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file?" -exec sed -i.bak -e 's/de_hecklist/data/g; s/secry/send/g' {} +
```

You can replace `-name "file?"` with whatever pattern that matches your files, or remove it entirely to edit all files.

The `-maxdepth 1` instructs `find` to not enter subdirectories, so that only the files matching `file?` in the current directory are changed.

The `-i.bak` option in `sed` makes a backup of the files. You can remove it if you don't need a backup. Also note that this `-i` (`--in-place`) option is a GNU `sed` extension, and therefore is not POSIX compliant, but since you use Linux, this will not be an issue.